# Visual C++ 2012 FatalExecutionEngineError

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm making a program in Visual Studio 2012 (I'm using 2012 because 2015 didn't seem to have the visual aspect for C++). I've been getting a FatalExecutionEngineError in the program when I close it specifically when I'm using 'WinMain' as the entry point instead of just 'main'. I tried running it without any code at all and got the same error. Does anyone have a suggestion for fixing this problem?

Note: My OS is Windows 7 Ultimate

Comment: clean your solution and then rebuild it again...not sure what is causing that though...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. I hadn't included Windows.h before and didn't have the correct parameters. I also had it's return type as void even though it apparently requires int.